# Rails, for each second in past week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to do something for each second in the past week and pass in the current epoch time as well... I'm not sure how to do this, but it seems really trivial, here is my pseudo code:

```
1.week.ago..Time.now do |second|
  puts second
end
```

How would I make this output the current time in ints for each second in that range?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
(1.week.ago.to_i..Time.now.to_i).each{ |second| puts "second=#{second}"}
```

Comment: This works (tested with 1.minute.ago, but should work similarly with week), was going to post a similar solution.